# "JNI ERROR: GetStringUTFChars received NULL jstring" when call MediaCodec.configure()

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-mediacodec

I want to get raw data from *.mp3 file. I found [`MediaCodec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec) would be nice for me, but I'm getting

```
A/64.myproj: java_vm_ext.cc:542] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: GetStringUTFChars received NULL jstring
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]     in call to GetStringUTFChars
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]     from void android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(java.lang.String[], java.lang.Object[], android.view.Surface, android.media.MediaCrypto, android.os.IHwBinder, int)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x74071ee0 self=0xed774000
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | sysTid=1552 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf2463494
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | state=R schedstat=( 993990291 519274343 1413 ) utm=70 stm=29 core=1 HZ=100
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | stack=0xff31c000-0xff31e000 stackSize=8MB
```

on `mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, 0)`.

Here is the code:

```
public static void foo(String filepath) throws IOException {
    MediaExtractor mediaExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
    mediaExtractor.setDataSource(filepath);
    MediaFormat mediaFormat = mediaExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
    mediaExtractor.release();
    MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mmr.setDataSource(filepath);
    final long durationMs = Long.parseLong(mmr.extractMetadata(
            MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));
    mmr.release();

    MediaCodecList mediaCodecList = new MediaCodecList(MediaCodecList.ALL_CODECS);
    mediaFormat.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, null);
    String codecName = mediaCodecList.findDecoderForFormat(mediaFormat);
    MediaCodec mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(codecName);
    mediaCodec.setCallback(new MediaCodec.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onInputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec codec, int index) {
            File file = new File(filepath);
            int size = (int) file.length();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
            ByteBuffer in = codec.getInputBuffer(index);
            try (BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
                buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                in.put(bytes);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            codec.queueInputBuffer(
                    index,
                    0,
                    size,
                    durationMs * 1000L,
                    MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOutputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec codec, int index, MediaCodec.BufferInfo info) {
            ByteBuffer out = codec.getOutputBuffer(index);
            short buf[] = out.asShortBuffer().array();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(MediaCodec codec, MediaCodec.CodecException e) {}

        @Override
        public void onOutputFormatChanged(MediaCodec codec, MediaFormat format) {}
    });
    mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, 0);
    mediaCodec.start();
}
```

and [the huge stack trace on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/VWpfHicE).

Comment: The documentation for `findDecoderForFormat` says that it returns _"null if no such codec has been found"_. Meanwhile, the documentation for `createByCodecName` says that the name you pass to it _"must never be null"_. So clearly you must handle that scenario.

Comment: `mediaFormat.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, null);` might be the problem. Just don't set it, it is usually not necessary. It might still be the manufacturers fault for not handling `null` values properly. What device are you using?

Comment: @Michael, yes, but it isn't problem at the moment - MediaCodec is created properly, it would throw `NullPointerException` otherwise or something

Comment: @ChrisBe, I tried, no changes. Btw it already has `null` there by itself :) I'm using Android Studio's emulator - Nexus 5X API 28

Comment: Well, this is a JNI error, signaling that one value that is to be expected is of type `jstring`. [According to this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/pie-release/media/jni/android_media_Utils.cpp#168) no null check is performed in Pie when parsing media format. Could you post the values of the `MediaFormat`?  You can try to replace any `null` values with none-`null` ones and check if the error changes

Comment: @ChrisBe, I have checked values for 36 keys, they all are null except: `KEY_MIME`=`audio/mpeg`, `KEY_BIT_RATE`=`320000`, `KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT`=`2` and `KEY_SAMPLE_RATE`=`44100`. There is no more mandatory keys according to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat.html)

Comment: @Powercoder what do you mean by 'checked values for 36 keys'? Does the format contain all 36 keys? Note that the `toString()` method prints the entire format. Also, any `get...` method returns null (or 0) if it is not present, check with `containsKey`.

Comment: @ChrisBe, I meant I copy-pasted all keys from documentation tables. Sure, `toString()` looks easier. {encoder-delay=576, sample-rate=44100, pcm-encoding=2, track-id=1, durationUs=92551836, mime=audio/mpeg, channel-count=2, bitrate=320000, encoder-padding=1416, frame-rate=null}

Comment: hm, frame-rate is still null and that is probably the reason for the crash. have you tried to set it to an actual value? Try 25, one could hope that it'll be just ignored by mediacodec

Comment: @ChrisBe, Well, lol. It worked. I bet it is null because I'm decoding an audio format but ok. Thanks for helping.